# Connecting to a web server across networks

Tags: iis-7

I have a server sitting on two networks A & B. from here I run an application that publishes a web page using IIS. I can view this as servername/website name on network A. On network B I have a device with a WebServer. I can view the device web page from the server but not from network A.

Is this possible to somehow use the server to relay this website out to network A?

Comment: Try to rephrase your question using real examples with as much real data (e.g addressing) as possible. Now it's hard even to understand how many involved devices you have.

Comment: What you're looking for is known as a "reverse proxy". Searching for "iis reverse proxy" might give you some useful results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about `iis-7`, but the webserver should already be broadcasting to both networks, assuming you're only dealing with one webserver and that it is connected to two networks, and assuming it's not a special setup (and that `iis-7` doesn't change the natural way things work here). The webserver should have two local IP addresses (one for each network). You'll need to access the right local IP address for the network that you're on.

For instance, I've got a webserver running on my desktop. Both 192.168.0.20 (my wireless network adapter) and 192.168.0.19 (my non-wireless network adapter) will go to my website. However, they are on the same network (just using different network cards), but the same principle should apply if the network cards are connected to different networks.

You can also forward the webserver port (usually 80) on the router of either of your networks and just use your global IP address to connect (if you don't mind allowing the whole world the opportunity). If you have a dynamic IP address, it will change once in a while. You can get a domain name and use something like afraid.org, which gives you a link you can visit, which triggers an update of the IP address with your domain name (you can use the link in a program to automatically update the IP address at the appropriate times; I made one, if you need it).

EDIT: On analyzing your question further (sorry if I didn't understand it right the first time), it looks like you've got a computer, which is on both networks (and which although is a server of some kind, is not a webserver), and you have a webserver on one network (and not the other, too), and you're wanting the other network to be able to access the webserver.

Well, the simple answer would be to connect to the other network, too, from the webserver, and then follow my answer above. The next simple answer would be to do the global IP thing I talked about (assuming you're allowed to forward ports on the router and globally host the website from it). I'm sure there's a more direct, but maybe less simple solution, but someone else will have to give it, at this time. It sounds like Bob's reverse proxy suggestion is probably that solution.